# How to Create a Certifcate using EJBCA API

Tags: ejbca

Please guide me on how to perform following using EJBCA API:

1. Create a Certificate using EJBCA API in Java code.
2. Provision (Upload) the created certificate on to Application Server using EJBCA API in Java code.
3. Validate a Certificate using EJBCA API in Java code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to any specific API, as there are several APIs and protocols in EJBCA? Otherwise I would suggest using standard IETF protocols for most of these.

1. Use the CMP protocol, [RFC4210](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4210.txt). In Java you can use the [BouncyCastle](http://bouncycastle.org/) library that supports CMP. You can also find example code in [EJBCA CMP test sources](https://svn.cesecore.eu/svn/ejbca/trunk/ejbca/modules/systemtests/src-test/org/ejbca/core/protocol/cmp/).
2. For this there is not standard API. Every Application server is different. Is it a JBoss server? An Apache HTTP? Or a Tomcat? You can simply use a combination of the Application servers native commands and some bash scripting to provision the certificate. Unless you want to look at other tools, such as the [ACME protocol](https://github.com/ietf-wg-acme/acme/)?
3. Validation typically refers to checking if the certificate is revoked or not. The best protocol to do this is OCSP, [RFC6960](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6960.txt). EJBCA fully supports OCSP, and you can again use the BouncyCastle library to write Java code to query the EJBCA OCSP responder. Sample code is also again available in [EJBCA OCSP test sources](https://svn.cesecore.eu/svn/ejbca/trunk/ejbca/modules/systemtests/src-test/org/ejbca/core/protocol/ocsp/).